# c++ std::fstream. How do I read a number at the start of the line (a float or an int), and then skip to the next? Using named variables so no loop

Tags: c++, fstream, cin, txt

I have a text file in the following format:

```
100 #gravity
5000 #power
30 #fulcrum
```

I want to assign these values to named variables, like so:

```
void Game::reloadAttributes()
{
    float test1, test2, test3;
    
    string line;
    std::fstream file;
    file.open("attribs.txt");

    if (file.is_open()) {                

        cin >> test1;
        file.ignore(50, '\n');

        cin >> test2;
        file.ignore(50, '\n');

        cin >> test3;
        file.ignore(50, '\n');

        file.close();
    } 
    else
    {
        cout << "\n****Couldn't open file!!****\n" << endl;
    }

    cout << ">>>> " << test1 << ", " << test2 << ", " << test3 << endl;
}
```

Of course, these aren't destined for the local test variables, but in fields belonging to the Game class, just using these to test its reading correctly. The program just hangs at cin >> test1. Ive tried using getLine(file, line) just beforehand, that didnt work. What am I doing wrong? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object of type `istream` (in this case `cin`) takes user input. So of course the program will wait for you to input a value and then store it inside `test1`, `test2`, and `test3` respectively.

To fix your issue, just replace `cin` with `file` as such:

```
file >> test1;
file.ignore(50, '\n');

file >> test2;
file.ignore(50, '\n');

file >> test3;
file.ignore(50, '\n');

file.close();
```

### Output:

```
>>>> 100, 5000, 30
```

Comment: "*An object of type `istream` ... takes user input*" - that is misleading. Not all `istream`s take in *user* input.  Only the `std::cin` stream specifically does.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `cin` instead of `file` for your input lines.

Instead of `cin >> test1;`, do `file >> test1;`. Then it should work fine.